# A tool, an inquiry, a tragedy

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> In entirety, an entirety
>   Naught but a void otherwise
>   Take bits from me, ye shall find:
>   A tool, an inquiry, a tragedy

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> A WHOLE

In entirety, an entirety

> The word "Whole" in its full form means... well, a full form.

Naught but a void otherwise

> But it also sounds like the word "hole", which is an empty space.

Take bits from me, ye shall find:
A tool, an inquiry, a tragedy

> By choosing certain letters from the word, we get "HOE", a farming tool, "WHO", a question, and "WOE", a sad thing indeed!

Comment: Perfect answer, and so soon too! Was it too easy? :>

Comment: @VotBear: the difficulty of riddles is very subjective: if you'd left it a little later you might get more people attempting it! I just happened to "see" the answer but some others may not.